# What are the disadvantages of targeting the JVM instead of x86?

Tags: compiler-construction, jvm

I'm developing a new language. My initial target was to compile to native x86 for the Windows platform, but now I am in doubt.

I've seen some new languages target the JVM (most notable Scala and Clojure). Ofcourse it's not possible to port every language *easily* to the JVM; to do so may lead to small changes to the language and it's design.

After posing this question, I even doubted more about this decision. I now know some "pro" JVM arguments. The original question was: *is targetting the JVM a good idea, when creating a compiler for a new language?*

Updated the question: **What are the disadvantages of targeting the JVM instead of x86 on Windows?**

Comment: No dynamic typing?  That'll come as a surprise to the dynamically-typed scripting languages already running on the JVM...

Comment: Great question, very interesting. I suggest you enhance the title, so that it mentions the intention to use the JVM for a compiler.

Comment: And there's no such thing as "native dynamic typing". The VM runtime either supports it or it doesn't, the native machine is much too low level for that sort of concept.

Comment: @skaffman, as static typing is a high-level concept for dynamic typed VM's, dynamic typing is high-level for static typed VM's. Let's say: with "native" I mean it's implemented at the lowest level, not at a higher level.

Comment: @skaffman: have you looked at the bizarre contortions those dynamically-typed scripting languages have to go through to make it work?

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: they don't go through bizarre contortions to make it *work*, they go to bizarre contortions to make it *fast*. But that is really not something unique to the JVM. Natively implemented dynamic language *also* go to bizarre contortions to make it fast, it's just different contortions. Have you looked into the implementations of any high-performance Smalltalk VMs? Actually, HotSpot *is* a re-branded high-performance Smalltalk VM!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Targeting the JVM is a pretty tried and tested approach. The fact that Clojure, Scala, JRuby and [many other languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) have done so successfully should give you some reassurance.

My view overall is that the JVM is probably the best target at the moment for new/experimental languages, particularly if you hope to achieve cross platform capability while taking advantage of a truly fantastic JIT compiler and a wealth of very powerful libraries.

Having said that, the main disadvantages you may encounter targeting the JVM are in my opinion as follows:

- Lack of tail recursion support at the bytecode level. There are ways around this (e.g. see Clojure's "recur" special form) but it is annoying for some language implementations, particularly functional languages. Will probably eventually be fixed in future versions of Java.
- Slightly obvious, but you need a JVM installed on your client. Usually not a problem nowadays, but there are still cases where this can be tricky.
- Primitives (int, long, float etc.) in Java behave differently from the rest of the object system. Again you can work around this but it is some extra hassle for language implementers.

Some potentially useful/interesting links:

- [ASM bytecode analysis and manipulation framework](http://asm.ow2.org/). This is a great tool, 
  I believe it is what what Clojure uses under the hood.
- [Clojure source code](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure)

Comment: How *could* tail recursion be supported at the bytecode level?  If an exception occurs within a recursive call, the stack-trace is supposed to include all the nested calls, is it not?  If a language specifies that something which looks like a tail-recursive call may not generate a stack-trace entry, then replacing it with a loop would be legitimate, but unless the language specifies that I don't think the JVM should make that inference.

Comment: I guess the JVM could implement tail recursion in a backwards compatible way where language implementers could indicate to the JVM (perhaps at a method level) that they don't care about the full stack-trace. Languages that want TCO could ask for this, everyone else would get the old behaviour.

Comment: I think it would be better to have a tail-call construct to the language, and require programs using that feature to employ a newer version of the JVM (which likewise supports it).  There is no way a program targeting the old JVM can support million-deep "recursion" while having tail calls be as efficient as conventional calls, and having the old JVM convert tail calls to conventional calls would be worse than having it simply refuse outright to load the code.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at targeting the LLVM instead of the JVM. The LLVM can be used to target a number of architectures, including x86.

There's more to portability than simple CPU support, but the LLVM can help a lot and still give you native code, if you like.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a language for the JVM, you have also the great advantage that a huge library is at your feet, which can be readily used from within your language. This is most likely not the case if you compile for x86. I assume you won't make it possible to include e.g. C-headers in your language without having a C parser.

For this reason Scala, Groovy and others are a such a success.

At the current stage of development of the JVM, and with the new enhancement for supporting scripting languages, I would just target the JVM, because odds are your language will be executed faster then with every runtime library you could ever create for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should only target the JVM if you're happy to have the runtime part of your code totally dependent on third party code and requiring your users to install such, *and*, the JVM will provide substantial features that you can't reasonably develop yourself or ask people to extend for this purpose (e.g. OS headers in C++), *and*, you're happy with the JNI as your interface to native code (and thus, other managed code like .NET).

Ultimately, it totally depends on the resources available to you and how you pictured language interop. If you're going to use the JVM to provide a lot of features, and you're happy for the interop to be awful, then use it. Else, I think you should reconsider.